# List subclasses of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, inheritance

### Description

- Given a class, return all its subclasses (recursively).
- As you can see I've eliminated recursion using a stack.

### What I want reviewed

- Is there a better way to do this?
- How can I make this code more generic and easier to use?
- Is it pythonic?
- Better way to eliminate recursion?

### Code

```
def all_subclasses(cls):

    if cls == type:
        raise ValueError("Invalid class - 'type' is not a class")

    subclasses = set()

    stack = []
    try:
        immediate_subclasses = cls.__subclasses__()
    except (TypeError, AttributeError) as ex:
        raise ValueError("Invalid class" + repr(cls)) from ex

    for subclass in immediate_subclasses:
        stack.append(subclass)       

    while stack:
        sub = stack.pop()
        subclasses.add(sub)
        try:
            sub_subclasses = sub.__subclasses__()
        except (TypeError, AttributeError) as _:
           continue
        if sub_subclasses:
            stack.extend(sub_subclasses)

    return list(subclasses)
```

### Tests

```
import unittest

from class_util import all_subclasses

def names(classes): 
    return sorted([cls.__name__ for cls in classes])

class A:
    @classmethod
    def all_subclasses(cls):
        return all_subclasses(cls)

class B(A):
    pass


class C(B):
    pass

class D(C):
    pass

class E(C):
    pass

class F(E, C):
    pass

class AllSublassesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_nested_classes(self):
        self.assertEqual(names(A.all_subclasses()), ["B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])

    def test_work_with_buitins(self):
        self.assertTrue(names(all_subclasses(dict)))
        self.assertTrue(names(all_subclasses(tuple)))   
        self.assertTrue(names(all_subclasses(list)))

    def test_value_error_is_raised_on_invalid_classes(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, all_subclasses, type)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, all_subclasses, "")
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, all_subclasses, None)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, all_subclasses, [])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- While working on the stack you are using `stack.extend`. You can also use this in the part where you add the immediate subclasses.
- There is no need to check if a list is empty before using `extend`, if it is empty it will just do nothing.
- If you don't need the exception, just don't catch it with `as _`.
- Not sure if you should be doing `if cls is type` instead of `if cls == type`.

```
def all_subclasses(cls):

    if cls == type:
        raise ValueError("Invalid class - 'type' is not a class")

    subclasses = set()

    stack = []
    try:
        stack.extend(cls.__subclasses__())
    except (TypeError, AttributeError) as ex:
        raise ValueError("Invalid class" + repr(cls)) from ex  

    while stack:
        sub = stack.pop()
        subclasses.add(sub)
        try:
            stack.extend(sub.__subclasses__())
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
           continue

    return list(subclasses)
```

One way to optimize this further is to make sure you don't visit a class multiple times:

```
    while stack:
        sub = stack.pop()
        subclasses.add(sub)
        try:
            stack.extend(s for s in sub.__subclasses__() if s not in subclasses)
        except (TypeError, AttributeError):
           continue
```

This should prevent having to visit (almost) every class twice with convoluted hierarchies like this:

```
    A
  /   \
 B     C
  \   /
    D
 / | | \
E  F G ...
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for this. I'll post more questions when I can.